# Suse: How to update a single package in SLES10 SP4

Tags: upgrade, suse, glibc, patch, sles

I am in the middle of an activity and have never worked with SLES10 SP4

In SLES11 `zypper update glibc*` updates all glibc packages .. but this is not working in SLES10 SP4 .. can someone tell me how to update a single package in SLES10 SP4

Answer (score 0):

Should be the same, but the `glibc` ghost `vuln` patched RPMs are only in paid support version repo LTSS included. The standard SLES 10 SP4 updates repo is end of support.

Comment: Yes i have bought Ltss support from suse. And i have still not found how to update just 1 single package .. the abve specifed by me patches the entire server :(

Comment: normally a "zypper update glibc*" patches only the glibc files with its required packages (rpm dependencies) from the repo. alternative you can download the glibc*.rpm files and install them directly with rpm -Uvh name1.rpm name2.rpm ... - but this is not recommended if there other rpm dependencies.

Comment: this should work as well: # zypper up --no-recommends glibc* and install the glibc patches without dependencies